# Cascading function (animate) and $('this')

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have 3 divs with mouseenter, mouseleave and click functions. The problem is in the click event - I'm having a bit of trouble making it's animate cascading function work. I think the problem is on the function's "second level" '$(this)':

```
$('.compositos_DBitems_container').on('click', '> div > div:not(.compositos_highlighted)', function () {

    // De-highlight currently highlighted item
    function dehighlight_clickedCompositos() {
        $('.compositos_DBitems_container > div > div.compositos_highlighted').removeClass('compositos_highlighted')
        .animate({ 'width': '70%', 'height': '70%', 'top': '10%' }, 150, 'swing')
        .find('p').animate({ 'font-size': '73%' }, 150, 'swing', function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'width': '90%', 'height': '90%', 'top': '0%' }, 150, 'swing')
            .find('p').animate({ 'font-size': '100%', 'color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' }, 150, 'swing');
        });
    }

    // Highlight clicked item
    $(this).addClass('compositos_highlighted').animate({ 'width': '70%', 'height': '70%', 'top': '10%' }, 300, 'swing')
    .find('p').animate({ 'font-size': '73%' }, 300, 'swing', function () {
        $(this).animate({ 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', 'top': '-4.5%' }, 300, 'swing')
        .find('p').animate({ 'font-size': '110%', 'color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' }, 300, 'swing');
    });

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BMeMt/)

This is a 2 level animation: when you click it, the div shrinks and then grows back in - it's doing the 1st level only, though.

Help?

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know precisely what you want to do afterwards but I guess you should save a reference to the jquery element to access it afterwards. This was referencing the p element and not the parent anymore in the callback function.

```
var button = $(this);
$(this).addClass('compositos_highlighted').animate({ 'width': '70%', 'height': '70%',     'top': '10%' }, 300, 'swing')
.find('p').animate({ 'font-size': '73%' }, 300, 'swing', function () {
    button.animate({ 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', 'top': '-4.5%' }, 300, 'swing')
    .find('p').animate({ 'font-size': '110%', 'color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' }, 300, 'swing');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BMeMt/6/